# Keeping height of div static with an ajax call that inserts html

Tags: javascript, css, ajax, styles

I have an Ajax call that inserts a div with several p elements with text.  The problem is whenever I click the button to make the Ajax get, the height of the whole container will change because I haven't set a static height (I have set a specific width though) for the container in my css stylesheet.

Whenever I click the button to load the Ajax info, there will be a brief instant where you can see the container gets really small because I'm just replacing the text in the container with other text.  Is there a simple css solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using the CSS `min-height` property, which would prevent the container from shrinking to a size too short (http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_min-height.asp). For instance,

```
#myContainer {
  min-height: 600px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
min-height:400px;//Whatever height you want it to not get smaller than
height:400px;//Whatever height you want the div to be
```

so that it doesn't gets small and use

```
overflow:auto;
```

so that it doesn't get big instead becomes scrollable when more content received than expected. Using overflow:auto will only show the scrollbars when the content overflows. i.e, when needed.

In case you want the scrollbars no matter what use

`overflow:scroll;`//Scrollbars will appear by default, even if not needed.

Comment: Talk about `scroll`, too, as the OP might want that functionality. Or, from your edit, explain the difference between `auto` and `scroll`.